# transparent borders with css 3

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to make the borders of an element semi-transparent? using purely css? like the modal window that facebook uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rgba()` such that `background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);` is the same as `background-color: rgb(255,0,0); opacity: 0.5;`

For your border, do something like this `border: 3px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.3);`

http://jsfiddle.net/robert/b3e3v/

Comment: how come the corners are darker?

Comment: Because of the way the browser is rendering the border, it's overlapping on the bottom like that.

Comment: @Rena: Webkit overlaps the borders whereas firefox doesn't. You can hide this by giving it a border-radius equal to the width of the border. That seems to change the way it paints itself.

Answer (score 2):

RGBA is only half of an answer, the other half is background-clip.
See there: http://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/

Answer (score 1):

Use two divs ... one for the border the other for the inner area.  Then set the background color of the outer div to have a transparency value:

```
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it in a hackish manner. Here is an article on how to make transparent/semi-transparent borders around a header section:

[Transparent borders](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Web-Style-Sheets/Altering-the-Border-Opacity-of-an-HTML-Element-with-the-RGBA-CSS3-Property/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="lightbox">
/* Set transparent background with PNG
   add padding to push inside box inward */

  <div id="lightbox-inside">
    /* Set white background in here */
  </div>

</div>
```

2 divs means proper compadibility.  just remember to set your opacity(for ie and all others respectively)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve that very easily! Use this code :

```
border: 14px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
```

Where 0.50 is the opacity!

Hope it helps!